# cublasDdot CUBLAS_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR

Tags: c, cuda

I implemented a precondition conjugate gradient method to resolve a `Ax = B` problem by using `CUBLAS` lib and `CUDA`.

My code works fine when it deals with the `40000x40000` implicit matrix `A`.

However, when I increase the size  to `130000x130000`, it gives `CUBLAS_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR` from `cublasDdot` method.

Does anyone know why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: Is your GPU a dedicated compute device or display GPU?

Comment: Does your code check the status of every CUDA and CUBLAS API call prior to the invocation of cublasDdot()? It seems the error inside of cublasDdot() could simply be a followup error to an earlier, unchecked, out-of-memory condition, i.e. a failed allocation call.

Comment: I figured out the problem. Actually, it caused by the GPU watchdog. @talonmies the GPU is a display GPU. That's why we have the problem. Thanks for your replies!

Comment: @Howard: Please add your resolution as an answer. It takes the question off the unanswered list and leaves your solution for the next person that comes along.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem. Actually, it is not caused by the `CUBLAS API`. When I give larger size matrix to the solver, it takes longer time to solve it. However, the time is over the GPU watchdog limit, then the solver is terminated by the watchdog process. So, we bought a new GPU as our dedicated one and solved the problem. @talonmies thanks for your advises!